# How can I search and replace dollar using vim visual mode

Tags: vim, special-characters

I'm editing a shell to be used as a here document. I want  to replace the $ dollar signs  with \$. How can I  do this when vim uses $ as a line ending.

```
cat > goodband.txt <<EOF 

function bestband
{
  local JON=$1
  local BON=$2
}

EOF


I want  to replace with 


cat > goodband.txt <<EOF 

function bestband
{
  local JON=\$1
  local BON=\$2
}

EOF
```

I went into visual mode, highlighted the block and tried :s/$/\$\g. But I  highlighted and replaced the line endings.

Comment: For someone who is looking for a solution to replace all the $ with \$, you can use `%s/\$/\\\$/g`

Answer (score 9):

`$` is a special marker for the end of line. If you want to replace *literal* `$` characters, you need to escape them, such as moving to the start of the `JON` line and entering:

```
:.,.+1s/\$/\\$/g
```

(current line and next).

For affecting the visual selection in the case where it's not so easy to work out the line range, you can just use the `'<` and `'>` markers:

```
:'<,'>s/\$/\\$/g
```

Comment: No need for `:global` here. The correct range for the visual selection is `'<,'>`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this `<,'>s/\$/\\\$/g`

Comment: Your answer is missing the initial `'`; `'<` means first selected line. Also, you just need _two_ backslashes in the replacement part (to escape the literal backslash); `$` has only special meaning in the search pattern, not in the replacement (but it doesn't hurt to escape it).